# FloodFill iphone implementation.How to do this?

Tags: iphone, image, colors, flood-fill

I'm going to developing an application for coloring the image.For that floodfill algorithm is used.I don't know how to implement the floodfill algorithm in iphone.I want to do the same way as android..
i'm having the code for implementation of floodfill in android.But,i really don't know how to do for iphone as same as android.

Here,Flood fill algorithm is used to coloring the image.I have done upto choosing the color from color palette.now,i want apply the color to image(part by part).just consider,Rose has many parts like.,lief,sticky bulb,etc..

Each and every part of image is placed as seperate imageview.All the image views are placed in uiview.

please any one help me out to do this.

Thanks for your consideration and effort

Renuga

Comment: Anyone give me some solution for this...

Comment: same issue i'm facing i like to color some part of the image using floodfill.